# JS get document of iFrame from inside

Tags: javascript, iframe, document

I know about `contentDocument`, but it's not for the case.

`event.target` is the `body` of the iFrame. How can I get its `document` (using the "owner" doc's script)?

Comment: are you try to go from the parent to the child or from the child to the parent?

Comment: you try to use the `top` property?

Comment: Same origin? If not, forget it

Comment: same origin -- same server

Answer (score 0):

Forget the body. Any event from inside the iFrame is enough.

```
event.view; // = [object Window]
event.view.parentFrame; // = <iframe>
```